# How to disable click to button same time

Tags: android

I create dynamically button in android tablet and I want to do disable click same time to buttons,how can I do this?? I want disable multi touch in tablet Can I disable multi touch in android tablet? Code is the below

```
                                                if (cevap_sayisi == 5) {


btn1.setText(answer
        .get(0));
btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stylebutton_iyi);
btn1.setTextSize(28);
btn1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
btn1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(
            View v) {
        // TODO
        // Auto-generated
        // method stub

        Cevapla(1,
                question_id);

    }

});


btn2.setText(answer
        .get(1));
btn2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stylebutton_orta);
btn2.setTextSize(28);
btn2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
btn2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(
            View v) {
        // TODO
        // Auto-generated
        // method stub

        Cevapla(2,
                question_id);

    }

});


btn3.setText(answer
        .get(2));
btn3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stylebutton_kotu);
btn3.setTextSize(28);
btn3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
btn3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(
            View v) {
        // TODO
        // Auto-generated
        // method stub

        Cevapla(3,
                question_id);

    }

});


btn4.setText(answer
        .get(3));
btn4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stylebutton_fena);
btn4.setTextSize(28);
btn4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
btn4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(
            View v) {
        // TODO
        // Auto-generated
        // method stub

        Cevapla(4,
                question_id);

    }

});


btn5.setText(answer
        .get(4));
btn5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stylebutton_cokiyi);
btn5.setTextSize(28);
btn5.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
btn5.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
btn5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(
            View v) {
        // TODO
        // Auto-generated
        // method stub

        Cevapla(5,
                question_id);

    }

});

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
     ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(
        new LayoutParams(
                320,
                120));

ll.addView(btn1, lp);
ll.addView(btn2, lp);
ll.addView(btn3, lp);
ll.addView(btn4, lp);
ll.addView(btn5, lp);
lm.addView(ll);
```

Comment: I solved problem                                               <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
</style>                                                                in Manifest                                             <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create button dynamically

Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("Hello");

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.addView(myButton, lp);

and to disable click use this

myButton.setEnabled(false);

To disable multitouch use this in manifest

< uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />

Hope this will help....

Comment: i don't think the manifest is working as you say, it disables the requirement but not the functionality itself, so you declare your app do not need multi-touch, but that does not mean the multi-touch will be stopped in your app.

Comment: When I used < uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" /> in android manifest it works but application view changed font size larged how can I prevent this?

Comment: I think you have to define style and put it in the manifest file android:theme     Use this link  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

btn.setclickable(false);
btn.setActivated(false);

Comment: it works, but still clickable same time buttons,how to provide multi touch button same time

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!CommonUtil.isFastDoubleClick()) {
            //to do sth
}
```

CommonUtils.java

```
private static long lastClickTime;  
public static boolean isFastDoubleClick() {  
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();  
        long timeD = time - lastClickTime;  
    if ( 0 < timeD && timeD < 500) {     
        return true;     
        }     
        lastClickTime = time;     
        return false;     
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where can I add this code. I create many dynamically button can I add many times in your code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean . U can add this code "if (!CommonUtil.isFastDoubleClick()) {}" in method Cevapla()